# How do I set up this "Adzilen" portfolio in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, portfolio

I downloaded this Bootstrap portfolio to modify and use in Angular, but I can't implement it so that the bootstrap and the changes work, can you help me with the config step by step that you have to have. I'm suffering a lot from this.

I did npm install bootstrap, I passed the content of the Index to a component in the HTML, I got the CSS configuration and threw it in the component's CSS, I already played in the global CSS, but regardless of where or what I do, it doesn't adopt the Bootstrap style .

Download Portfólio =>
https://awaikenthemes.com/template/adzilen-creative-portfolio-template/